# Why my environment variables are not overriding appsettings.json

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, connection-string

I have an application that uses ASP.NET Core Web API and mongodb, they both are containerized by docker-compose, and I don't know why my appsettings is not been overridden.

[This is my `appsettings.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OGpi.png)

[This is my service in the docker-compose.override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gATY.png)

And I expected (and in the teacher worked) this connection string to be overridden, but actually it's not.

I don't know if it is relevant but my ASP.NET Core is version 7 and his is 5

My connection string is not being overridden

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The : delimiter doesn't work with environment variable hierarchical
> keys on all platforms. For example, the : delimiter is not supported
> by Bash. The double underscore (__), which is supported on all
> platforms, automatically replaces any : delimiters in environment
> variables.

(Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider)

So you should change it to something like:

```
"DatabaseSettings__ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"
```

Comment: Thank you bro it worked, you're my savior <3